# Auto inject an object in all tests or a test class from a fixture in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to initialize an http wrapper class in a fixture. This fixture will be used in all the tests. Is it possible to auto inject in all tests so that i do following:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()
def init_wrapper():
   wrapper = HttpWrapper()
```

I want automatically do wrapper object in tests without passing fixture name in the test as parameter

```
def test_something():
    wrapper.get_call()

def test_somthing1():
    wrapper.post_call()
```

If above is not possibe can I set a initiaized wrapper object to my TestClass as a member variable so that i can use it as

```
def test_something():
    self.wrapper.get_call()
```

The reason is I dont want to pass init_wrapper in all the testcase. which i know will be used by all the tests

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a pytest fixture to be used by all tests within a given tests subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135100/how-to-define-a-pytest-fixture-to-be-used-by-all-tests-within-a-given-tests-subd)