# How to define a pytest fixture to be used by all tests within a given tests subdirectory?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

Given a directory `tests` with a few subdirectories each containing test modules, how can one create a `pytest` fixture to be run before each test found in a particular subdirectory only?

```
tests
├── __init__.py
├── subdirXX
│   ├── test_module1.py
│   ├── test_module2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── subdirYY
│   ├── test_module3.py
│   ├── test_module4.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

I'd like to have a fixture that will run before each test found in modules within the `subdirYY` only (in this case, in modules `test_module3.py` and `test_module4.py`).

I currently have a fixture defined twice, once inside each module within the `subdirYY` which works but is redundant:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def clean_directory():
   ...
```

If this is not possible to achieve, each of the tests within the `subdirYY` is decorated with a custom mark (`@pytest.mark.mycustommark`) so making sure that a certain fixture will run before each test marked with a particular custom mark is a viable option, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your autouse fixture in a `conftest.py` file inside `subdirYY`.

For more information, see the pytest docs about [sharing fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/fixture.html?highlight=conftest#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session) and the docs on [autouse fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/fixture.html?highlight=conftest#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids) which specifically mention `conftest.py`:

> if an autouse fixture is defined in a conftest.py file then all tests in all test modules belows its directory will invoke the fixture.